# @Nullable in Spring 5 is annotated with @Nonnull

Tags: spring, nullable

I just updated my project to use `Spring Boot 2.0.3` with `Spring Framework 5.0.7`.

And now I see that some parameters in methods of `MessageSource` are annotated with Spring's shiny new `@Nullable` annotation. But due to this annotation, IDEA 14 says that the appropriate parameters cannot be `null` (**SURPRISE!**).

As I understand that's due to the fact that `@Nullable` is annotated with `@Nonnull`:

```
@Nonnull(
    when = When.MAYBE
)
```

What was the reason to mark annotation with a logically opposite one?

Comment: My quick guess is, that Spring and IDEA have different interpretations of "when". To find out who's right, or wrong, you'd want to look into the specification of `javax.annotation.Nonnull.when` but since this is based on a dead JSR you won't have much luck searching for any official specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @StephanHerrmann, it's related to the original JSR.
So the idea is that `null` value is allowed in some cases - just to make code self-documented.
Similar approach is actually used in `javax.annotation.Nullable`:

```
@Documented
@TypeQualifierNickname
@Nonnull(when = When.UNKNOWN)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Nullable {

}
```

In latest IDEA versions this annotation is supported (or WILL be supported) [out of the box](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15540?focusedCommentId=152034&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-152034).
To fix IDEA warning in older versions you just need to [add the Spring's annotation manually](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15540?focusedCommentId=152012&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-152012).